# Web.Config - StaticContent ClientCache setup for specific files

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, web-config

I want to be able to apply caching to Static files on my site.

I want the caching to apply to specific file extensions only but I'm not 100% certain of the syntax to add to my `web.config` file.

This is what I have so far:

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
  <remove fileExtension=".jpg" />
  <remove fileExtension=".png" />
  <remove fileExtension=".gif" />
  <remove fileExtension=".css" />
  <remove fileExtension=".js" />
  <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpg" mimeType="image/jpg"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".png" mimeType="image/png"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".gif" mimeType="image/gif"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript"/>
</staticContent>
```

Am I right in thinking this will apply 1 day cache to the static files with the following extensions?

- .svg
- .jpg
- .png
- .gif
- .css
- .js

It *looks* like the `clientCache` node in the config doesn't directly tie to the `mimeMap` statements. I don't necessarily want the `clientCache` to work for files outside of the specified list.

Also, are there any 'gotchas' to this method I should be wary of?

Thanks for any help.

Site details:

- ASP.NET MVC 3
- IIS7

Answer (score 2):

You could apply a client cache-control setting by using the below code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".text" mimeType="text/plain" />
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
        </staticContent>
        <rewrite>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="RewriteCacheControlForHTMLFiles" preCondition="FileEndsWithHtml">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Cache_Control" pattern=".*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=86400" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="FileEndsWithHtml">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="\.html$" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Note:use your file extentions.

You could also use location tag to do this but for that, you need to move that specific file extension files to another folder any apply this setting to that folder.

```
  <configuration>
  <!-- Note the use of the 'location' tag to specify which 
       folder this applies to-->
  <location path="images">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="00:00:15" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yes. As far as I can see. My original question was to confirm the syntax and any caveats that I should be aware of in using that setup.

Comment: if you do not want to use that you could use location tag or URL rewrite rule.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've gone ahead with the code I had above and it seems to be working well

Comment: if your issue is resolved please mark the post as answer this will help other people who face a similar issue.